# VSCode, Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Since a few days ago I am not able to login to an oci linux instance via vscode remote ssh..

I don't remember doing any changes either on the server side or on the client side.

I have 2 linux servers, one of them is a VM linux ubuntu on OCI, and the other one is a webserver from a popular provider.
Until a few days ago I was able to connect to both of them remotely via VSCODE, where I also did all my work and everything.

Since then, i cannot login anymore (only via vscode). For example, both putty and winscp connections are working for both of the servers, but for vs code, nothing works.

For the hosted webserver, I was not getting any error, it just said that it cannot connect to the host, not even password prompt. I went and deleted .vscode-server folder from my /home/user on the server, and then it resumed working as usual.

However, for the OCI instance, i did the same, but it doesn't work.

1. When trying to connect to the OCI instance, I get Failed to set up socket for dynamic port forward to remote port... full log here:
   https://pastebin.com/Sh7TJdiu

I deleted both .ssh and .vscode folders from my client (w11). I also have 2 users on the OCI instance, none of them works. However, i also deleted everything .vscode-server from those users /home/user.

What I think maybe have caused this, is a few days ago i generated a ssh-keygen pair from my w11 cmd, added my private key in putty and the public one in .ssh/authorized_keys in one of the users in oci instance. However, for a few days this worked perfectly (i used to connect to this without any password). But then, it stopped working, and i don't know why. I also deleted everything inside authorized_keys since then and still nothing.

I also tried creating a new linux dummy user without anything in it, just to test if i can connect to that, and i got the exact same error.

Can someone please help?

```
[1]: https://pastebin.com/Sh7TJdiu
```